# Ajax requests messing up when insert element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have noticed now that my ajax calls are messing up after the first call, well.. I insert element and about 5 seconds aftrer insert element they mess up and say their disconnected? Is this a thing with just insert element or is their an actual error here... here are the images of the errors im getting when inserting element

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62V0s.jpg) to view the images of the error.s

Here is all of my ajax code (there is a lot) but loadIt() function is where I am always calling the ajax calls every 5 seconds and that is the function that is erroring. (Look at the very bottom of the code for the loadIt function.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var loginContent = "";
var staffContent = "";
var activeContent = "";
var $loginBox = $("#login_content");
var $activeBox = $("#active_content");
var $staffBox = $("#staffmessagesArea");
loadIt();
loadMessages();

function loadMessages()
{
    $.ajax({

     type: "GET",
     url: '<?php echo $config['website']['url']; ?>/assets/hk/ajax/staff_messages.php',
     success: function(data) {
          if (staffContent != data)
          {
              $('#staffmessagesArea').html(data);
          }
     }

   });
}

function loadIt() 
{
    $.get("<?php echo $config['website']['url']; ?>/assets/hk/ajax/recent_logins.php",function(data) {

    if (loginContent != data) {
    $loginBox.html(data); 
    loginContent=data;
    }
    setTimeout(loadIt,5000);
    });

    $.get("<?php echo $config['website']['url']; ?>/assets/hk/ajax/active_content.php",function(data) {
    if (activeContent != data) {
    $activeBox.html(data); 
    activeContent=data;
    }
    setTimeout(loadIt,5000);
    });
}  </script>
```

Contents of the recent_logins.php file

```
<?php
require_once '../../other/connection.php';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user_logins` ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) 
{
    echo '' . $row['Login_Username'] . '<br>' . $row['Login_Timestamp'] . ' - ' . $row['Login_Ip'] . '<br><br>';
}
?>
```

I am using xampp as a web server on a 1GB RAM Windows 2012 R2 Server VPS..
I also checked this on my local computer with windows 8.1 and 4GB Ram with xampp on localhost, but it still did it?? Changing too IIS sort of fixed it (I didn't notice any problems) but I really want to be with xampp..

I must also tell you my html file contains of about 1200 lines..

Comment: Please scale this code down to only code relevant to problem. Can see numerous ajax requests..have no idea what to look at

Comment: I have edited the question.